# How many ways to generate unique multiplication result from given set?

Tags: combinations

From set `{2, 2, 3, 5}`, I can have 8 ways to generate unique multiplication result, which:
- two number multiplication: 2*2, 2*3, 2*5, 3*5
- three number multiplication: 2*2*3, 2*2*5, 2*3*5
- four number multiplication: 2*2*3*5

Then, how many unique multiplication result I can generate for following set

```
{ 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2}
```

What is the formula?

*Edit: only prime numbers are allowed in the set

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "unique"? For example, 3*4 and 2*2*3 are both equal to 12, so the uniqueness is given by the set of factors more than by the result? Or it depends on the result, but also on the number of factors (for example, only 1 multiplication gives 12 within the two-factors multiplications)? If that is the case, would 3*4 and 2*6 be considered equal or different?

Comment: I have modified it to only containing prime number. let's say a*b produce same result as c*d then it count as 1 unique multiplication. So it is more result oriented

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to programmatically calculate that? Or are you looking for an equation? Because if the former is the case you can apply the `n choose k` formula to store combinations in an `array`,`list`, etc. , remove the duplicates and count the length. and you have your answer

Comment: @KenWhite Where should I ask this question then? But I do need this for programming though

Comment: @xgeorgekx I am looking for equation and then using that equation to programmatically calculate huge set of prime number efficiently

Comment: If `pi` are the distinct prime numbers in the (multi)set and `ni` are the number of times the respective `pi` appears, then the result is `Product(ni+1) - N - 1` (oh and `N` is the number of disticnt primes.) So for you last example would be `(5+1)*(5+1)*(4+1)*(3+1)*(3+1) - 5 - 1 = 2874`

Comment: @ypercube the equation looks good to me. I hope you can explain how you got that equation from (the (ni+1) thing)

Comment: There are 5 elevens, 5 sevens, 4 fives, 3 threes and 3 twos. And there are in total 5 distinct primes in the set. The (`-N-1`) calculation is needed because you don't include the "one factor" and the "zero factor" multiplications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every positive integer has a unique prime factorization. So your products will all be of the form

$$ 11^a\cdot 7^b\cdot 5^c\cdot 3^d\cdot 2^e $$

where $0\le a,b,c,d,e$ and $a,b\le 5;\; c\le 4;\; d,e\le 3$. Which gives you

$$ 6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 4 = 2880 $$

possible numbers of this form. But that includes the case of zero factors (in which case you have $a=b=c=d=e=0$ and the product is $1$) as well as the cases of one factor ($a+b+c+d+e=1$, $5$ alternatives). Therefore your actual number is

$$ 6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 4 - 1 - 5 = 2874 $$

This generalizes to other multisets in an obvious way. If prime number $i$ (its actual value is irrelevant) occurs $k_i$ times, and you have $n$ such factors in total, then the number of distinct non-trivial products is

$$ (k_1+1)\cdot(k_2+1)\cdots(k_n+1) - 1 - n =
\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(k_i+1)\right) - 1 - n $$

Comment: where/how did you derive this equation from? I mean how did you know to calculate the exponent and add it with 1 beforehand? I am novice in math.

Comment: @kuratago: It follows from the inequalities you have for $a$ through $e$. If all five have to be integers, simply count the number of possible values for each one. E.g. $e$ can be 0, 1, 2 or 3 since you can have anything between zero and three twos included in your product.